# whitelisted all ip address, still cant connect to mongodb atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, networking, port, router

I have whitelisted all IP addresses in the network access tab of MongoDB atlas. I tried connecting to the cluster via shell, compass and my node.js application. But all of them are failing and giving me a timeout error.

The connection is successful when I am connecting via my phone network, but it is failing on my home network. I think the problem is with the router. Can someone please help me out?

[image: here is a screenshot]

Comment: Outbound port blocked by your ISP?

Comment: Might also be a DNS problem, a lot of ISPs provide DNS servers that don't support SRV records.